# How much epoll events to wait in a cooperative event-loop?

Tags: asynchronous, network-programming, epoll, systems-programming

> **tl;dr:** Considering [`epoll_wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html):
>
> ```c
> int epoll_wait(int epfd, struct epoll_event *events, int maxevents, int timeout);
> ```
>
> How to guess or set `maxevents`?

I am building a cooperative event-loop that does not expose
continuations (aka. callbacks) and where procedures are [not
colored](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/). That can be achieved thanks to [`call/cc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation).

I do not know how to configure `epoll_wait`'s `maxevents`.

Here are the features of the event loop:

- The event loop runs coroutines that may be spawned before the event loop start or during the event loop is running.
- A coroutine can sleep without blocking other coroutines,
- Another POSIX thread can spawn a coroutine in an event-loop.

Here is the pseudo-code of the gist of the event-loop:

```py
while loop.has_work?:
    # Resume all coroutines that have be spawned
    for coroutine in loop.coroutines-waiting:
        resume(coroutine)
    # Resume all coroutines that are sleeping
    for coroutine in loop.coroutines-to-wake-up:
        resume(coroutine)
    # Wait for MAXEVENTS
    for event in epoll.wait(..., MAXEVENTS, ...):
        coroutine = loop.coroutine_waiting_for_event[event]
        resume(coroutine)
```

The question is: how to determine `MAXEVENTS`? Should `MAXEVENTS` be equal to the total number of events registred with [`epoll_ctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html)?

Comment: What does the Scheme language have to do with this?

Comment: It was part of the context. I removed the tag `scheme`.